# if $U$ is open, is $U=\operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Cl}(U)$)?

Tags: general-topology

$U$ is a subset of a topological space X.
If $U$ is open, is $$ U=\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(U)) ? $$
$\operatorname{int}$ is the interior and $\operatorname{cl}$ the topological closure.
I'm sure it works with clopen sets and i think it also works in the general case, but i'm not sure.

Comment: It's not true in general, only $U\subseteq int(Cl(U)) $

Comment: @k.stm what does this notation mean, $(-1..1)$, and in particular $(1..1)$? Did you mean $(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$?

Comment: @Mirko Er, yes. I meant $(-1..0)∪(0..1)$. Of course. I’ll delete the comment. So “$(-1..0)∪(0..1)$ in $ℝ$ is the standard counterexample.” is what I wanted to say. And yes, that’s notation for intervals. It’s the superior notation and I try to spread it. See Zsbán Ambrus’s comment [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42929/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work in general, this kind of sets are called regular open sets. It is easy to prove that all regular open sets are open, but the converse is not true. Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology and the set $U=(0,1)\cup (1,2)$. It is clear that $U$ is an open set, since its the union of two open sets, nevertheless $$\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(U))=(0,2)$$ Because $1$ is a point in the boundary of $U$ such that there is some open neighborhood V of $1$ such that $V\cap (X\setminus \operatorname{cl}(U))=\emptyset$. That is indeed the way you can characterize regular open sets.

**Proposition**

An open set $A\subset X$ is regular open if and only if for every $x \in \operatorname{bd}(A)$ and every open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, $U\cap (X\setminus \operatorname{cl}(A))\neq \emptyset$

Comment: Your last proposition is contradicted by your given example $U=(0,1)\cup (1,2) $.

Comment: @Alearner sorry, I was missing a $Cl$ (corrected now). Thanks (+1)

Answer (score 5):

Not necessarily. Consider the topological space $X = [0, 1]$ (with the usual topology), and $U = (0, 1)$.